# How can i filter with checkboxes

Tags: sql-server, django, django-templates

I want to filter with checkboxes from column values

Code:

```
 cursor.execute("[Prueba].[dbo].[N]" + "'" + str(format_min) + "'," + "'" + str(format_max) + "'")
 qs = cursor.fetchall()
```

it returns the values [image with values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK6U0.png)

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="h1" name="h1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="h1">
                  <b>H1</b>
                </label>
                          <br />
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="h2" name="h2">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="h2">
                  <b>H2</b>
```

I want to click on checkbox h1 and filter by h1 machines

Comment: Although I don't understand what you ask, the way you are making that query, you are **vulnerable to SQL Injection**.

Comment: I want to filter by checkbox h1 is checked filter all prog_reg_codigo_alt with value h1